# Registering Multiple Signals in Django

Tags: python, django, signals

I'm trying to register multiple signals on one model. It seems that as I register an additional signal, it removes the previous signal.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save,post_delete
from my.app.models import Resource


@receiver(post_save,sender=Resource)
def ResourceSaved(sender,**kwargs):
    print "Saved"

@receiver(post_delete,sender=Resource)
def ResourceSaved(sender,**kwargs):
    print "Deleted"
```

I've taken a look around the docs, but I keep finding details on how to create custom signals in a class formate. Not how to register in class format.

I would imagine I can do something like this:

```
@reciver(sender=Resource)
class SignalAnsweringMachine(object):
    def post_delete(self,**kwargs):
        print "delete"
    def post_save(self,**kwargs):
        print "save"
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are (probably unintentionally) redefining ResourceSaved. Try this instead:

```
@receiver(post_save,sender=Resource)
def ResourceSaved(sender,**kwargs):
    print "Saved"

@receiver(post_delete,sender=Resource)
def ResourceDeleted(sender,**kwargs):
    print "Deleted"
```

Answer (score 10):

Since the merge of [#18454](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18454) released in [Django 1.5](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/1.5/#minor-features) you can connect more than one signal by supplying a list of signals:

```py
@receiver([post_save, post_delete], sender=Resource)
def ResourceSaved(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Answer (score 7):

I use this short form to register two or more handlers.

In my case I clear cached categories list.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from ..models import Category

all_categories = []

# Post save handler for Category model to clear "all_categores" variable
@receiver(post_save, sender=Category)
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Category)
def post_save_category(sender, **kwargs):
    # clean cached categories
    global all_categories
    all_categories = []
```